# Positive lower bound for a function defined as a series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How we could know that for the function $f(x)$ below if there exist (not exist) a constant $C>0$ such that $f(x)\geq C$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n)^{2}+1}$$
(i.e., $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)\neq 0$)

**EDIT:** I got something which I'm not sure if its correct or not:

If $x>0$ is too large then there is $n_{o}$ such that $x<n_{o}$, so we split the summation
$$\sum_{n=1}^{n_{o}-1}\frac{1}{(x-n)^{2}+1}+\sum_{n=n_{o}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n)^{2}+1}$$

and for any $n\geq n_{o}$ we have $(x-(n+k))^{2}< (\epsilon+k)^{2}$ in this case the second summation will be finite, where $\epsilon = n_{o}-x$.

Comment: Do you expect the same behavior as $x\to \infty$ and $x\to -\infty$?  How might they differ?

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: I just want to check if both limits are nonzero.

Comment: Cherly: I think I understand that.  Interesting.  Would you mind sharing where the problem came from?

Comment: It came up during the class, discussion about interchanging the order of limit and summation.

Comment: Note that the assertion in your last two lines of the question is false: the term on the left goes to infinity when $n$ does, while the right hand side is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

When $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $|x-k|\leq \frac{1}{2}$.  Thus $(x-k)^2\leq \frac{1}{4}$.  What does this imply about $f(x)$ for $x>0$, and how does it answer the $x\to \infty$ part?

When $x<0$, $x$ will no longer be so close to positive integers.  Note that $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,1]$, so it suffices to find the sequence limit $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(-k)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(k+n)^2+1}.$$ The series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}$ converges, which means that the sequence of partial sums converges, and

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(k+n)^2+1}\ \ =\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}\to 0.$$

That is, $f(-k)\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ because the tail of a convergent series goes to $0$.

Comment: Nice! What about the other limit at $+\infty$?

Comment: @Cherly: I am inviting you to investigate how the $+\infty$ case is handled by the observation in the first paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Related problem: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2/208407#208407). Here is a closed form for the series, in terms of the [psi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) that may help you analyze your problem

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n)^{2}+1}=-\frac{1}{2}\,i \left( -\psi \left( 1-i-x \right) +\psi \left( 1+i-x \right) 
 \right)\,.$$

Another interesting closed form is when you sum the series from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, you get the following function

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n)^{2}+1}={\frac {\pi \,\cosh \left( \pi  \right) \sinh \left( \pi  \right) }{
 \left( \cosh \left( \pi  \right)  \right) ^{2}- \left( \cos \left( 
\pi \,x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
 $$

Comment: So for the second form the limit at $\pm\infty$ is zero, this is also interesting, thanks! How did you get the $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ functions to be involved here?

Comment: @Cherly: The second function is periodic, and has no limits at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Actually, the second function can be used to help answer the question of what happens to the original function at $+\infty$.  Note that $f(x)+f(-x) +\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is periodic and nonconstant, hence has no limits at $\pm\infty$, hence $f$ cannot have limits at both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.  (What I have said here doesn't quite show that $f$ has a positive lower bound in one direction, however, for which the method hinted in my answer, or perhaps use of the Psi functions, may be of more use.)