# $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Now we want to prove:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2}$$
$\alpha$ >0 and not an integer.
According to poisson summation formula
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{2\pi inx}.$$
So, if we let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, then
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+x)^2}$$
Therefore, if we can prove that
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} e^{-2\pi inx}dx e^{2\pi inx}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi x)^2}$$
Then it will be done.
But I don't know how to prove
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} e^{-2\pi inx}dx e^{2\pi inx}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi x)^2}$$
Who could give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: [Interesing...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left) we can square termwise.

Comment: Here is a [related problem 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2), [related problem 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314968/how-many-ways-to-calculate-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1un2-where).

Comment: @user39843: I found your question under my post. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262321/fourier-transform-of-fx-frac1x26x13) for the answer.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal thx! It would be helpful.

Comment: Does this series converge uniformly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper technique is documented at [MSE 112161](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/) and at [MSE 3056578](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056578/).

Comment: This one is better done with a rectangular contour aligned with half-integers (real and imaginary).