# How to prove that $\frac {\pi^2}{ \sin(\pi z)^2 } = \sum_{n=-\infty , n\neq 0 }^{n=\infty} 1/ (z-n)^2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, problem-solving

The following question was part of my complex analysis assignment and I am not able to prove it.

> How to prove that $$\frac {\pi^2 } { \sin(\pi z)^2 }  = \sum_{n=-\infty , n \neq0 }^{n=\infty} \frac{1}{(z-n)^2 }$$

I tried by using the identity $$\sin(\pi z) = \pi z \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1- \left(\frac zn \right)^2 \right) $$ But that is in product so can't be used here.

I don't have any other ideas except these. Actually the prof is known in department to be not good in teaching and online classes added more to it. In particularly in these type of questions where I have to prove some identity I am having very much difficulty.

It is my very humble request to you to help me.

Comment: Look at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_theorem

Comment: Take the derivative of the $\log$ of the product. But the series is easier to prove: the RHS minus the LHS is an entire periodic function easily seen to be bounded, thus constant, and since it vanishes at $i\infty$..

Comment: There is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056578/sum-n-infty-infty-frac1u-n2-frac-pi2-sin-pi-u2?rq=1).

Comment: It is weird that $n=0$ is excluded in the summation, since the term corresponding to $n=0$ should also be included to make the identity hold true. Also, I suspect that this is a duplicate of the posting mention in Pedro Tamaroff's comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(u +n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi u)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056578/sum-n-infty-infty-frac1u-n2-frac-pi2-sin-pi-u2)

Comment: @Gary Can you please have a look at this question to which I put a bounty. No one is replying to it.

Comment: As written, the identity is false. The $n=0$ term needs to be included to get $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$. Without that term, the sum is $\frac{\pi^2}3$ when $z=0$, and $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ blows up at $z=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard argument is as follows:

1. Let $f$ denote your infinite sum, and let $g$ denote your function built out of the sine.
2. Show that $f$ and $g$ are meromorphic functions with double poles only at the integers except zero. They also have no roots.
3. This means that the difference $h=f-g$ is a holomorphic function, but it is also a function that satisfies $h(z)=h(z+1)$. Can you conclude?

Comment: what is the contradiction in (3) can you please tell. I have understood all 3 points but can't conclude.

Comment: @Avenger There's no contradiction, rather, you want to show that $h$ must be constant.

Comment: How does h(z+1 ) =h(z) implies that h is a constant ? Sorry I am coming back so late but I have been not well

Comment: Can you please reply?

Comment: Show that $h=f-g$ is bounded on $0 \leq \Re z \leq 1$. Because of $h(z)=h(z+1)$ it is then bounded on the whole of the complex plane. Argue that $h$ is entire. Hence, by Liouville's theorem, $h$ is constant.

Comment: @Gary I got your argument but I am unable to prove h to be bounded on $0\leq Rz \leq 1$. Can you please help with that?

Comment: @Avenger Show that $h(z)$ is holomorphic (has no poles, ect.). Show that $h(z) \to 0$ as $\Im z \to \pm \infty$ in $0\leq \Re z \leq 1$. Conclude from this that $h(z)$ must be bounded in that strip.

Comment: @Gary I have shown that  h(z) is holomorphic but I am unable to understand what you mean by symbol  $  \Im z $. You were using Re z symbol in last comment which I think means Real part of z

Comment: Imaginary part of $z$. So the function is close to zero in the closed strip $0 \leq \Re z \leq 1$ after some time as you go up or down. So it is bounded after some time. But in the remaining finite part, it is bounded because it is a compact set and $h$ is continuous on it.

Comment: @Gary Is there an easy or elegant way of proving it that you are aware of , I am only aware of this method: Putting z =x+ iy in the function h(z) and then using the fact that $0\leq x \leq 1 $ and limit y tends to $\infty$. If there is any other method can you please tell me?

Comment: @Avenger That is correct. I would just say it is obvious that $h(z)$ tends to zero as $\Im z \to \pm \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a complex analysis problem.

This is a sum of a series by residues.

$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = -\{ sum\, of\, residues\, of\, \pi\cot(\pi z)f(z)\, at\, all\, the\, poles\, of\, f(z) \} \tag{1}$$

Using $x$ to avoid confusion with $z$. $n$ is the variable of summation so replace it with $x$.

$$f(x) = \frac1{(z-x)^2} \tag{2}$$

$f(x)$ has a double pole at $x=z$.

$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = - \pi \lim_{x \rightarrow z} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ (x-z)^2 \frac{\cot(\pi x)}{(z-x)^2}\right] \tag{3}$$

$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = - \pi \lim_{x \rightarrow z} \frac{d}{dx} {\cot(\pi x)} \tag{4}$$

$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = - \pi \lim_{x \rightarrow z}  \frac{-\pi}{\sin^2(\pi x)} \tag{5}$$

$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)} \tag{6}$$

Comment: "$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = -\{ sum\, of\, residues\, of\, \pi\cot(\pi z)f(z)\, at\, all\, the\, poles\, of\, f(z) \} $" Can you please write a proof of this statement or give some refence?

Comment: @Avenger see for example [this](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf).

Comment: Theorem 3.2. in @Evangelopoulos F  reference.  My reference is ancient: Schaum's outline Series, Theory and problems of complex variables - Murray R. Spiegel , 4th printing 1987, pg 187 Summation of series.

Comment: Take a look at Example 4.3.  @Evangelopoulos F reference.  Instead of $z \rightarrow \frac1{2}$ just leave it as $z$.

Comment: @arthur I am busy. But awarded you bounty. If I have a question I will comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This can be solved [using only real analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077) as well.