# Why is $\frac{1}{(u+z)^2}\in\Theta(1/N^2)$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057017/91974) is it mentioned that

$$\frac{1}{(u+z)^2}\in\Theta(1/N^2),$$

I know that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{1}{z^2}dz=0$$
where $C$ is any circle centered at the origin. But what about
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{1}{(u+z)^2}dz?$$
Can we make a change of variables to get that this integral is also zero?

Comment: Please specify how $u,z,N$ are related.  Say $z$ is on a certain contour defined in terms $N$, and we are interested in what happens when $N \to \infty$.

Comment: For the unrelated "I know" part.  The function $z \mapsto 1/(u+z)^2$ has meromorphic antiderivative $-1/(u+z)$, so integrating on a closed curve (that does not pass through $-u$) is certainly $0$.