# Help in finding the sum of the series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4+n^2+1}$$

I tried breaking into factors but it is not telescoping.

$$\frac {1}{(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1)} = \frac {1}{2n} \left(\frac {1}{n^2-n+1} - \frac {1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$$

Comment: but what about the $\frac {1}{2n}$

Comment: Couple of suggestions. When using partial fractions you should have the degree of the numerator to be one less than that of the denominator. Once you've got that worked out try completing the square of each denominator.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski but how can I apply it here? The numerator has degree 0. How can   increase the degree?

Comment: Well once you find the right coefficients, they would cancel correctly if you performed the addition.

Comment: in other words, you should be solving for $\frac{1}{n^4+n^2+1} = \frac{An+B}{n^2+n+1} + \frac{Cn+D}{n^2-n+1}$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305820/how-do-i-calculate-sum-n-geq1-frac1n41/308221#308221)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{3}$. Then:

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^4+n^2+1}=\frac{1}{i\sqrt{3}}\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2-\omega}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2-\omega^2}\right)=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{6}\tanh\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
since we can deal with series like the ones appearing in the middle term through the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the hyperbolic sine function. In particular, the identity:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n^2+z^2}=\frac{1+\pi z\coth(\pi z)}{2z^2}$$
is well-known.

Comment: can't it be done with more elementary method ?

Comment: @LucyferZedd: do you consider Fourier/Laplace/Mellin transforms as elementary?

Comment: Amazing! Such clever use of the cube roots of unity.