# Finding $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^4+1}$ via residue theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to find $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^4+1}$ via residue theorem. 
Especially form of cotangent or tangent functions.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384780/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n4a4/384839#384839

Comment: http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305820

Comment: Wow amazing! Thanks guys!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^4+1}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305820/how-do-i-calculate-sum-n-geq1-frac1n41)

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^4-a^4} = \frac{1}{2a^2}-\frac{\pi}{4 a^3}(\cot \pi a+\coth \pi a)$$

Hence for $a^4 = 1$...