# Value of the sum of the series $ \sum\frac{1}{4n^2 + 2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence

According to Wolfram Mathematica it holds
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4k^2 + 2k} =  1-\log(2) .
$$

How can one prove this?

Comment: What is $\frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{2k+1}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{4n^2+2n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406918/evaluating-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac14n22n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that $${1\over 4k^2 + 2k} = {1\over 2k(2k+1)}= {1\over 2k}-{1\over 2k+1}$$

Therefore $$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{N}{1\over 4k^2 + 2k} &=
\sum_{k=1}^{N}{{1\over 2k}-{1\over 2k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{N}{{1\over k}-{1\over 2k+1}-{1\over 2k}}\\
&=H_N-H_{2N}+1
\end{align}$$

Where $H$ is the Harmonic Series. Now since $H_N = \ln N + \gamma + o(1)$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant, what follows is that :$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{N}{1\over 4k^2 + 2k} &=1+H_N-H_{2N} \\
&=1+\ln N-\ln2N+o(1)\\
&=1-\ln\frac{2N}N+o(1)\\
&= 1-\ln 2 + o(1)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum \dfrac{1}{4k^2+2k}=\sum\dfrac{1}{2k(2k+1)}=\sum \left(\dfrac{1}{2k}-\dfrac{1}{2k+1}\right)=\ldots$