# Find the Fourier integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \cosh\left(\,x\,\right)}\,
{\rm e}^{2\pi{\rm i}tx}\,{\rm d}x\,.
$$

I tried contour integral ( real line and half circle ) to use residue theorem, but I think it does not vanish on the half circle.

I also just tried to find the answer in WolframAlpha but it didn't work.

How can I calculate this integral ?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607141/fourier-transform-of-fx-frac1exe-x2).

Comment: This is simply the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in disguise. After letting $t=e^x$, as @FelixMarin already did in his answer, substitute $u=\dfrac1{t^2+1}$. Then use Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to brush up the final result, and bring it to its desired form.

Comment: Mathematica gives $\pi\,\mathrm{sech}(\pi^2 t)$ which agrees with Felix Marin's and my answer.

Comment: Or see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434334/eigenfunction-of-the-fourier-transform/434452#434452) for different way to evaluate this integral using the residue theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue of $\dfrac{\color{#C00000}{e^{2\pi itz}}}{\color{#00A000}{\cosh(z)}}$ at $z=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi i$ is $\color{#00A000}{(-1)^{n-1}i}\,\color{#C00000}{e^{-(2n+1)\pi^2t}}$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Use the contour
$$
\gamma=[-R,R]\,\cup\,\overbrace{R+iR[0,1]}^{|\mathrm{Re}(z)|=R}\,\cup\,\overbrace{[R,-R]+iR}^{|\mathrm{Im}(z)|=R}\,\cup\,\overbrace{-R+iR[1,0]}^{|\mathrm{Re}(z)|=R}
$$
where $R=k\pi$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. As $R\to\infty$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi itx}}{\cosh(x)}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_\gamma\frac{e^{2\pi itz}}{\cosh(z)}\mathrm{d}z\\
&=(2\pi i)\,i\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}e^{-(2n+1)\pi^2t}\\
&=\frac{2\pi e^{-\pi^2t}}{1+e^{-2\pi^2t}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi^2t)}
\end{align}
$$

---

The integral along all contours but $[-R,R]$ vanish:

When $|\mathrm{Re}(z)|=k\pi$,
$$
\left|\frac{e^{2\pi itz}}{\cosh(z)}\right|\le\frac{e^{-2\pi t\mathrm{Im}(z)}}{\sinh(k\pi)}
$$
When $\mathrm{Im}(z)=k\pi$,
$$
\left|\frac{e^{2\pi itz}}{\cosh(z)}\right|\le\frac{e^{-2\pi^2kt}}{\cosh(\mathrm{Re}(z))}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \cosh\pars{x}}\,\expo{2\pi\ic tx}\,\dd x}
=2\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\pars{\expo{x}}^{2\pi\,\ic\,t} \over \pars{\expo{x}}^{2} + 1}
\pars{\expo{x}\,\dd x}}^{\ds{\dsc{\expo{x}}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{x}}}
=\dsc{2\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2\pi\,\ic\,t} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=2\bracks{2\pi\ic\,{\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/2}}^{2\pi\,\ic\,t} \over 2\ic}
+2\pi\ic\,{\pars{\expo{3\ic\pi/2}}^{2\pi\,\ic\,t} \over -2\ic}
-\int_{\infty}^{0}{x^{2\pi\,\ic\,t}\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic}}^{2\pi\,\ic\,t}
\over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=2\pi\expo{-\pi^{2}\,t} - 2\pi\expo{-3\pi^{2}\,t}
+\expo{-4\pi^{2}\,t}\ \dsc{2\int^{\infty}_{0}{x^{2\pi\,\ic\,t}
\over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}
\end{align}
where we used a 'key-hole contour' as depicted in the following picture:

[image]'

Integrand poles are at $\dsc{\expo{\ic\pi/2} = \ic}$ and
$\dsc{\expo{3\ic\pi/2} = -\ic}$ according to the $\ds{x^{2\pi\ic t}\,}$-branch cut.

> Then,

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \cosh\pars{x}}\,\expo{2\pi\ic tx}\,\dd x}
=\dsc{2\int^{\infty}_{0}{x^{2\pi\,\ic\,t}\over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}
=2\pi\,{\expo{-\pi^{2}\,t} - \expo{-3\pi^{2}\,t} \over 1 - \expo{-4\pi^{2}\,t}}
\\[5mm]&=2\pi\,{\expo{\pi^{2}\,t} - \expo{-\pi^{2}\,t}
\over \expo{\pi^{2}\,t} - \expo{-2\pi^{2}\,t}}
=2\pi\,{\sinh\pars{\pi^{2}\,t} \over \sinh\pars{2\pi^{2}\,t}}
={\pi \over \cosh\pars{\pi^{2}\,t}}
=\color{#66f}{\large\pi\sech\pars{\pi^{2} t}}\,,\qquad t \in {\mathbb R}
\end{align}

Comment: It took a while to see what you were using a keyhole contour to evaluate the integral in red (similar to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216)). It might be nice to mention the contours used and the residues computed.

Comment: In general lines, more words are usually welcome!

Comment: @robjohn I just added a picture. I'm quite bad for drawing. So, I have to borrow them from the Web. We do those calculations so many times that we expect everybody get the whole idea right away. Thanks for pointing out the missing contour.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the rectangular contour $[-R, R] \cup \big(R + i [0, \pi] \big) \cup \big( i \pi + [-R, R] \big) \cup \big( -R + i [0,\pi] \big)$ (properly oriented to close the loop), and check that the contribution along the length-$\pi$ endpieces fall off to zero as $R \to \infty$.

Note that 
$\cosh (r + i \pi) = \cosh(r) \cosh(i \pi) + \sinh (r) \sinh (i \pi) = - \cosh(r)$,
and so if $\hat f(t)$ denotes the desired Fourier transform, then it's not hard to see that
$$
(1 + e^{-2 \pi^2 t}) \hat f(t) = 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}_{x = \frac{i \pi}{2}} \frac{e^{2 \pi i x t}}{\cosh (x)} \, .
$$

Comment: There infinitely many singularities in the upper half plane.

Comment: @robjohn and my contour encircles precisely one of them.

Comment: Yes, but the residue at one of the singularities equals the difference of the integral along $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(-\infty+\pi i,\infty+\pi i)$ which turns out to be $1+e^{-2\pi^2t}$ times the integral along $(-\infty,\infty)$. It seems you are not taking into account the effect that the translation by $\pi i$ has on $e^{2\pi ixt}$; it multiplies it by $e^{-2\pi^2t}$.

Comment: Oops, I will correct the error.