# Definite integral of Jacobi Theta Function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form, theta-functions

I need to evaluate an integral that involves the Jacobi Theta Function $\vartheta_3(z,q)$ defined by [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) as
$$\vartheta_3(z,q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}e^{2inz}.$$
Specifically, I wish to evaluate
$$\int_0^1 q^{s-1} \vartheta^2_3(0,q) dq.$$

If that is possible, I would also like to do the same for other powers of $\vartheta_3(q)$
$$\int_0^1 q^{s-1} \vartheta^n_3(0,q) dq.$$

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1865696), I see that it is possible to evaluate this integral for $n=1$ to be
$$\int_0^1 q^{s-1} \vartheta_3(0,q) dq=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{s}}\coth(\pi x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^n \cos(\pi n)}{n^2+s}.$$ 
This was done by recognizing the Fourier Series
$$\frac{\pi}{x}\coth(\pi x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^n \cos(\pi n)}{n^2+x^2}.$$

Comment: have you tried to employ Ramanujan's Master theorem?

Comment: this here might also be of some interest: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811490/family-of-definite-integrals-involving-dedekind-eta-function-of-a-complex-argume

Comment: I have not tried Ramanujan's Master theorem, but it seems to be used for integrals to $\infty$, and $\vartheta_3$ blows up at $q=1$.
As for the other comment, I will try writing it with a complete elliptical integral of the first kind, though I see no easy way to write the $q^{s-1}$ in terms of the elliptic modulus.