# Do closed form expressions exist for $\int_0^1 \theta_3(x)\,dx$?

Tags: integration, number-theory, closed-form, theta-functions

The Jacobi theta (or “thetanull”) function $\theta_3$ is defined by:

$$\theta_3(x)= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathrm{e}^{-\pi n^2 x} = 1+ 2\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathrm{e}^{-\pi n^2 x} \qquad \Re(x) > 0$$

In his [2018 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06130.pdf), Dan Romik derived some very nice closed form expressions for the $d$-th derivative of $\theta_3(1)$. These expressions incorporate an intriguing [integer sequence](https://oeis.org/A317651) that might hide some undiscovered combinatoric structure.

Wondered whether similar closed forms could exist for subsequent integrals of $\theta_3$ from $0..1$, i.e.:

\begin{align}
I^{(1)}(1)&=\int_0^1 \theta_3(x)\,dx \\
I^{(2)}(1)&=\int_0^1 \int_0^y \theta_3(x)\,dx\, dy\\
I^{(3)}(1)&=\int_0^1 \int_0^z \int_0^y \theta_3(x)\,dx\, dy\, dz\\
\\ \cdots
\end{align}

Did manage to find a partial solution that is valid for any $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $d=0$:

$$I^{(d)}(1)=2\left(\,\sum_{k=0}^{d+1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1} \zeta \! \left(2 k \right)}{\left(d -k \right)! \pi^{k}}+\left(-1\right)^{d} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-\pi  \,n^{2}}}{\pi^{d} n^{2 d}}\right)$$

however, the second series didn't yield the desired closed form.

Found a few related questions about integrals of theta functions e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865615/curious-integrals-for-jacobi-theta-functions-int-01-vartheta-n0-qdq) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218679/definite-integral-of-jacobi-theta-function), however when we take $q=\mathrm{e}^{-\pi}$, these turned out to be indefinite integrals "in disguise".

Do closed forms for $I^{d}(1)$ exist? If so, my prediction is that the inevitable factor $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$ will be part of it again :-)

Comment: If you can access https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0_6 it could be interesting to look at it