# Closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta(2k)-\zeta(2k+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, closed-form

From WolframAlpha it seems that 
$$
\frac{1}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta(2k)-\zeta(2k+1)
$$

Could someone provide a proof for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where in WA is written that?

Comment: ...WA provided $\approx 0.4999999999999...$ not exactly $=1/2$.

Comment: Not that I asked, @Neves ...

Comment: Are you sure that the summation starts at k=0 ? Not k=1 instead ?

Comment: @claude, corrected that.

Comment: @Neves. Much better indeed !

Comment: What have you tried? Does methods from answers to your earlier question [Closed form for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta(4k-2)-\zeta(4k)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/617867/) apply?

Comment: @Neves Well, this is what WA gave me: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%3D1+to+infinity+[zeta%282k%29+-+zeta%282k%2B1%29]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing zeta-functions as series and changing the summation order does the trick.