# Show that two series are equal

Tags: harmonic-analysis

In my harmonic analysis class I have to prove that for all $a>0$ the following equality holds:
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-n^2\pi a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-k^2 \pi / a}.$$

I'd appreciate any help on how to approach this problem and where to start.

Thank you!

**Edited**

I tried to apply Poisson's summation formula. I guessed that the function is $$f(x)=\exp(-\frac{x^2a}{4\pi}).$$ On the right I get $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-n^2\pi a}$, as required. But for the left side I have to calculate the integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\exp(-i\omega x) dx ,$$ and I can't find the right substitution to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Poisson summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2).

Comment: @DanielFischer: thank you very much! I don't know how I missed that!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal:thanks! It helped a lot!

Comment: @Ludolila: You are very welcome.

Comment: @Ludolila: It is a natural thing to miss things sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the answer (after the useful hints), so in order not to leave this question open, I will answer it myself.

The main idea is to use Poisson summation formula:
$$\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} f(2\pi k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \hat{f}(n). $$
We start with setting $f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{4\pi a}}$, and thus $f(2\pi k)= e^{-\frac{k^2\pi}{a}}.$ Now we have to find $\hat{f}(\omega)$. At first I thought to solve the above-mentioned integral, but its not that easy. So I took a different approach (thought I couldn't remember where I've seen it before): we can differentiate $f(x)$ to get a differential equation $$f'(x)+\frac{x}{2\pi a} f(x)=0.$$
Applying Fourier transform to this equation we get 
$$\omega \hat{f}(\omega)+\frac{1}{2\pi a} (\hat{f})'(\omega).$$
Solving this diff. equation we get $\hat{f}(\omega)=2\pi\sqrt{a}e^{-\pi a \omega^2}$ and that proves the claim.