# Showing $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\pi an^2+2\pi ibn\right)=a^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{\pi(m-b)^2}{a}\right)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, exponential-sum

How do I show that

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\pi a n^2 + 2 \pi i bn\right) = a^{-\frac{1}{2}} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{\pi(m-b)^2}{a}\right)
\end{align}

is a valid identity?

Comment: See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2).

Comment: It is quite a long shot, @MhenniBenghorbal. Such identity can be seen as a consequence of the residue theorem, too, but Poisson summation formula is the standard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of [Poisson summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula). You just have to prove that, if
$$ f(x) = \exp\left(-\pi a x^2+2\pi i b x\right), $$
then its Fourier transform is:
$$ \widehat{f}(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a}}\exp\left(-\frac{(2b\pi+s)^2}{4a\pi}\right).$$