# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\over (1+x^2)^2}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over \tanh\left({\pi x\over 2}\right)}={\pi^2\over 8}-{1\over 2}?$

Tags: calculus, integration

**How may we show that**

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\over (1+x^2)^2}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over \tanh\left({\pi x\over 2}\right)}={\pi^2\over 8}-{1\over 2}\color{red}?\tag1$$

$u={x\over 2}\implies 2du=dx$

$$4\int_{0}^{\infty}{u\over (1+4u^2)^2}\coth(\pi u)\mathrm du\tag2$$

$$4\int_{0}^{\infty}{u\over (1+4u^2)^2}\cdot{e^{2u}+1\over e^{2u}-1}\mathrm du\tag3$$

$v=4u^2\implies du={dv\over 8u}$

$${1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{\sqrt{v}}+1\over e^{\sqrt{v}}-1}\cdot{\mathrm dv\over (1+v)^2}\tag4$$

$${1\over 2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(2)_k\over k!}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{\sqrt{v}}+1\over e^{\sqrt{v}}-1}\cdot v^k \mathrm dv\tag5$$

$e^{\sqrt{v}}=t\implies dv=2\sqrt{v}e^{\sqrt{v}}dt$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(2)_k\over k!}(-1)^k\int_{1}^{\infty}t\cdot{t+1\over t-1}\cdot \ln^{2k+1}(t) \mathrm dt\tag6$$

I don't what to do next ...

Comment: To make this look more interesting, write it as $$\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^1 \frac{1}{e^{\pi \sqrt{1/x-1}}-1} dx$$

Comment: Nice form (+1) @Brevan

Comment: You seem to keep commenting me about this alternate form then deleting it. This form isn't surprising actually - many zeta values can be written with integrals just like this one. However, I'm not sure how to directly evaluate this form... Perhaps a series expansion could be found?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Exploiting the evenness of the integrand, we can write

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\,dx=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\,dx \tag1$$

We can use contour integration to evaluate the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.  The function $\frac{z}{(1+z^2)^2\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}$ has simple poles at $z=i2n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus{0}$ and second order poles at $z=\pm i$.  Furthermore, we see that

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{i\phi}}{((Re^{i\phi})^2+1)^2\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi Re^{i\phi}}{2}\right)}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi=0$$

Therefore, closing the contour in the upper-half plane and invoking the residue theorem yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\,dx&=\pi i \sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{(1+z^2)^2\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)},z=i2n\right)\\\\&+\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{(1+z^2)^2\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)},z=i\right)\\\\
&=\pi i \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i4n}{\pi(4n^2-1)^2}+\pi i \left(\frac{-i\pi}{8}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac12 +\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

To evaluate the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4n}{(4n^2-1)^2}$ we note that we can write the series as a telescoping series and find

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4n}{(4n^2-1)^2}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)=\frac12$$

Comment: @brevanellefsen  Thanks Brevan!  Much appreciated.

Comment: very well done, would be a +10 if it where possible

Comment: (+1) , I was solving a similar integral 

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{x^2+1}\cdot\frac{dx}{\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x \right)} = \log(2)$$

I am stuck at proving the integral along the semi-circle goes to 0. How would you show it on the integral in the OP as well ?

Comment: @zaidalyafeai Note the behavior of $\cosh(z)$ for $z=Re^{i\phi}$ for large $R$.  And thank you for the up vote.

Comment: @tired Thank you my friend!

Comment: I am not sure if you have a shortcut because I have to deal with $\cosh(R\sin x ) , \cosh(R \cos x)$ in the denominator. Maybe I should bound it by 1 ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai   The meromorphic  function $\operatorname{sech} \left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)$ is $4i$-periodic and tends to $0$ as $\Re(z) \to \pm \infty$. So as long as the contour stays away from the poles on the imaginary axis, the magnitude of $\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)$ is bounded.

Comment: @zaidalyafeai Zaid, we can write $\cosh(z)$ as$$\cosh(R\cos(\phi))\cos(Rsin(\phi)) +i\sinh(R\cos(\phi)) \sin(R\sin(\phi))$$

Comment: @MarkViola, I think I overthought that easy problem,thanks and before I forget congrats for reaching the 100k milestone. Good job my friend.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach is to use the [partial fraction expansion of $\coth(z)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36#E3). 
(See [THIS QUESTION](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/208317) for derivations.)

$$\begin{align} & \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x^{2})^{2}} \coth \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \, dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x^{2})^{2}} \left(\frac{2}{\pi x} + \pi x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{\pi^{2}x^{2}}{4}+ n^{2}\pi^{2}}  \right) \, dx \\ &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})^{2}}\, dx+ \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{(1+x^{2})^{2}(x^{2}+ 4n^{2})} \, dx \\ &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2}(u) \, du \\&+  \small  \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4n^{2}}{(4n^{2}-1)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} \, dx- \frac{1}{4n^{2}-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})^{2}} \, dx - \frac{4n^{2}}{(4n^{2}-1)^{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}+4n^{2}} \, dx\right) \\ &= \frac{2}{\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{4n^{2}}{(4n^{2}-1)^{2}}\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{4n^{2}-1}\frac{\pi}{4}- \frac{4n^{2}}{(4n^{2}-1)^{2}} \frac{\pi}{4n} \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{2} + \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^{2}}-1 \right) \\  &= \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \frac{1}{4} \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-1 \right) \\ &=\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}-\frac{1}{2} \end{align}$$

Comment: I was thinking exactly of this solution before I read it.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}\,{\dd x\over \tanh\pars{\pi x/2}} =
> {\phantom{^{2}}\pi^2\over 8} - {1 \over 2}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\mbox{Note that}\quad
{1 \over \tanh\pars{\pi x/2}} = {\expo{\pi x} + 1 \over \expo{\pi x} - 1} =
1 + {2 \over \expo{\pi x} - 1}
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}\,
{\dd x\over \tanh\pars{\pi x/2}} =
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{1 \over 2}}\ +\
2\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}
\,{1 \over \expo{\pi x} - 1}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\quad x/2\ \mapsto\ x}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over
\bracks{x^{2} + \pars{1/2}^{2}}^{2}}
\,{1 \over \expo{2\pi x} - 1}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2} -
\left.{1 \over 2}\,\partiald{}{z}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over x^{2} + z^{2}}
\,{1 \over \expo{2\pi x} - 1}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ 1/2}
\end{align}

> With *Binet Second Formula*
> ( [see $\ds{\mathbf{\color{#000}{6.3.21}}}$ in A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm) ),

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}\,
{\dd x\over \tanh\pars{\pi x/2}} =
{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,\partiald{}{z}\bracks{\ln\pars{z} - 1/\pars{2z} - \Psi\pars{z} \over 2}_{\ z\ =\ 1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\bracks{2 - {1 \over 2}\,\Psi\,'\pars{1 \over 2}} =
{1 \over 4}\,\Psi\,'\pars{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{\phantom{^{2}}\pi^{2} \over 8} - {1 \over 2}}} \\ &
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\Psi\,'\pars{1/2} = 3\pars{\pi^{2}/6} = \pi^{2}/2}$ ( see $\ds{\mathbf{6.4.4}}$ in [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_260.htm) ).