# Proof for $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4-1}= \frac{7}{8}-\frac{\pi}{4}\coth(\pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can this identity be derived?
I have been searching the internet but I have no clue where to find a proof for this identity. Any help is highly appreciated.
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{1}{k^4-1}= \frac{7}{8}-\frac{\pi}{4}\coth(\pi)$$

Comment: Use partial fractions to break up the sum as $$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k \geq 2} \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) = \frac{3}{8},$$ and $$\frac{1}{4i}\sum_{k \geq 2} \left(\frac{1}{k-i} - \frac{1}{k+i}\right).$$  This last one you can probably relate to the residues of $\coth(z)$...  Have a look at : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2

Comment: I'd expect complex analysis on the function $f(z) = \frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^4 - 1}$ to be able to get the answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\frac{3}{4}\tag{1} $$
is trivial by telescoping and 
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k^2+1} = \frac{\pi\coth \pi+1}{2}\tag{2} $$
is a straightforward consequence of the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), since the [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) and the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) are conjugated via the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Comment: This was very helpful. It is possible to decompose fractions like 1/(k^8-1) into something like this, so the value of their limit can be given in close form?

Comment: @MisterSet: the approach is exactly the same.

Comment: Isn' t (1) equal to 3/4?

Comment: @MisterSet: any good book about Fourier series and the Fourier transform covers that topic pretty well. I can recommend Stein's book, for instance. Anyway, there are plenty of alternative approaches, based on Cauchy's integral formula or the Weierstrass product $$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the residue theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=N+1/2}\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z^2+1)}\,dz&=2\pi i \sum\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^2+1}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{2\cot(\pi i)}{2i}+\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{\pi(n^2+1)}\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

As $N\to \infty$, the integral on the left-hand side of $(1)$ vanishes.  Hence, we have

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1}=\pi \coth(\pi)$$

which after exploiting symmetry yields

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{\pi\coth(\pi)}{2}-1\tag 2$$

---

> Finally, using $\frac{1}{k^4-1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{k^2-1}-\frac{1}{k^2+1}\right)$ along with $(2)$ and the value of the telescoping series $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1}$ yields the coveted result.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.