# $ \frac{\pi^2\csc^2(\pi/x)}{x^2}= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1+(xn)^2}{(1-(xn)^2)^2}$. Where can I find some more series of this class?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

After reading [Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{a^2+n^2}=\frac{1+a\pi\coth a\pi}{2a^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2/208407#208407) and noodling around on wolfram alpha, I discovered

$$ \begin{align}
 &\coth(x \pi)=\frac{x}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+n^2} 
 & \cot(x \pi)= \frac{x}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}         \\
 & \text{csch}(x \pi )=\frac{x}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n }{x^2+n^2}} 
 &\csc(x \pi)= \frac{x}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n }{x^2-n^2}} \\
& \tanh(x \pi)=\frac{4x}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2+4x^2}}
&\tan(x \pi) = \frac{4x}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2-4x^2}} \end{align} $$

I suspect (but don't know for sure) that these can all be justified by milking the techniques from the link above.

**Go Go Gadget Calculus**

We should be able to derive a few more identities. For example,

$$ \Big(\cot(x \pi) \Big)'= \Big(\frac{x}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}} \Big )'$$

$$ \Big(\pi csc(\pi x)\Big)^2= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+n^2}{(x^2-n^2)^2}$$

And after some manipulations we can find

$$ \frac{\pi^2\csc^2(\pi/x)}{x^2}= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1+(xn)^2}{(1-(xn)^2)^2} $$
Lovely. We can write then 
$$\frac{\pi^2}{9}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty {\frac{1+(6n)^2}{(1-(6n)^2)^2}}$$
I have a feeling at this point that this must be a well-studied subject and I wonder where I can find some more identities of this class. Does anyone have a link/resource where I can read more on these. I don't really need their derivations if they are just the techniques of the link above + elementary calculus techniques. I am just looking for a well organized list that I can refer to.

Comment: $+1$ just for the "go go gadget calculus," because I get the reference. XD

Comment: Also... How do you render $\csch$?

Comment: You can always use \operatorname{csch}

Comment: Might want to newcommand it if you're gonna use it a lot. Just type \newcommand{\csch}{\operatorname{csch}} at the top of your question and everytime you type \csch it turns it to \operatorname{csch}. It's quicker and easier that way.

Comment: [This](https://zulfahmed.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/gradshteyntableintegrals.pdf) and [This](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) seem like they could be good resources.

Comment: $$\frac{\sin(x) \cos(x)}{x} =\prod_{n=0}^\infty \cos\bigg( \frac{x}{2^{n}} \bigg)$$
$$ \frac{1}{x}-2\cot(2x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} \tan(x/2^n) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have a list, but I can present the method to make a list systematically.

Let $P(x,n),Q(x,n)$ be two polynomials of $x,n$.

Suppose 
$$Q(x,r_1(x))=Q(x,r_2(x))=\cdots=Q(x,r_k(x))=0$$ for all $x$.

Suppose the sum 
$$S(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\frac{P(x,n)}{Q(x,n)}$$ converges whenever $r_{(\cdot)}(x)\not\in\mathbb Z$.

Then, by residue theorem,
$$S(x)=-\pi\sum^k_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=r_n(x)}\frac{\cot(\pi z)P(x,z)}{Q(x,z)}$$

(It is an issue that for some $x$, we might have $r_p(x)=r_q(x)$. When two or more $r$ functions take the same value, the residue should only be evaluated once.)

Answer (score 0):

There is some nice things to see here:

$$\tanh(x \pi)=\frac{4x}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2+4x^2}}$$

$$\Big(\tanh(x \pi) \Big)'=  \Big( \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{\frac{4x}{(2n+1)^2+4x^2}} \Big)'$$

$$ \pi\operatorname{sech}^2(\pi x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4\left(4n^2+4n-4x^2+1\right)}{\left(4n^2+4n+4x^2+1\right)^2}$$

Which is nice: taking $x=0$ we have

$$\pi^2=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4}{4n^2+4n+1}=8\Big(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{4n^2+4n+1}}\Big)$$

Interesting. I wonder if we can use this to demonstrate Takebe Kenko's somewhat similar looking (this can be found- with a tiny typo in denominator- on the last page of [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690896?origin=crossref&seq=16#metadata_info_tab_contents)):

$$\pi^2=4\Big(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}{(2n+2)
!} \Big) $$