# Evaluating the following integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\cos(ax)}{e^{bx}-1}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How can we compute this integral for all $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(b)>0$?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\cos(ax)}{e^{bx}-1}\ dx$$

Is there a way to compute it using methods from real analysis?

Comment: MMA gives the following answer: $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{\pi ^2
   \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi  a}{b}\right)}{b^2}\right),\Im(a)<\Re(b)\land
   \Re(b)>0\right]$$

Comment: ok , but how to get this answer ?!

Comment: As a different approach, let $c := \tfrac{2a\pi}{b}$, $f(z) = -ze^{-cz}$ and apply Abel-Plana formula: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\cos (ax)}{e^{bx}-1} dx = \frac{2\pi^2}{b^2} \cdot i\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ix)-f(-ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1} dx=\frac{2\pi^2}{b^2}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) -\frac {f(0)}2 - \int_0^\infty f(z) dz\right] .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**my attempt **

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\ cos(ax)}{e^{bx}-1}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\infty }x\ e^{-bnx}cos(ax)dx\\
\\
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\infty }x\ e^{-bnx}\ (e^{iax}-e^{-iax})dx=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }[\int_{0}^{\infty }x\ e^{-(bn-ia)}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty }x\ e^{-(bn+ia)}dx]\\
\\
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{\Gamma (2)}{(bn-ai)^2}+\frac{\Gamma (2)}{(bn+ia)^2})=\frac{1}{2b^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(n-\frac{ai}{b})^2}+\frac{1}{2b^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(n+\frac{ai}{b})^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}\\
\\$$
$$=\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{2b^2}(\Psi ^{1}(\frac{ai}{b})+\Psi ^{1}(\frac{-ai}{b}))\\\\\
\\
but\ we\ know\  \Psi  ^{(1)}(\frac{-ai}{b})=\Psi ^{(1)}(1-\frac{ai}{b})-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\\
\\
\\
\therefore \ I=\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{2b^2}\left ( \Psi ^{(1)}(1-\frac{ai}{b}) +\Psi ^{(1)}(\frac{ai}{b})-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right )\\
\\
\\
by\ using\ the\ reflection\ formula\ :\ \Psi ^{(1)}(1-\frac{ai}{b})+\Psi ^{(1)}(\frac{ai}{b})=\frac{\pi ^2}{sin^2(\frac{i\pi a}{b})}\\
\\$$

so we have 
$$\therefore I=\frac{1}{2a^2}+\frac{1}{2b^2}\left ( \frac{-\pi ^2}{sinh^2(\frac{\pi a}{b})} \right )\\
\\
\\
=\frac{1}{2a^2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{2b^2sinh^2(\frac{\pi a}{b})}\ \ \ \ \ \ , b>0$$

note that : 
$$\frac{\pi ^2}{sin^2(\frac{i\pi a}{b})}=-\frac{\pi ^2}{sinh^2(\frac{\pi a}{b})}$$

Answer (score 12):

We first start by converting our integral into a sum. We have that (by the geometric series):
$$\frac{1}{e^{bx}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-bxn}$$
Additionally, we have that (as can be found by simply finding an antiderivative):
$$\int_0^{\infty} x\cos(ax)e^{-bxn}~dx=\frac{-a^2+b^2 n^2}{(a^2+b^2 n^2)^2}$$
Therefore, the integral in question is equal to the following sum:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\cos(ax)}{e^{bx}-1}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-a^2+b^2n^2}{(a^2+b^2 n^2)^2}=-a^2 S_1+b^2 S_2 \tag{1}$$
Therefore, it suffices to compute the following sums:
$$S_1:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a^2+b^2 n^2)^2},\quad S_2:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(a^2+b^2 n^2)^2}$$
To do this, we start from the [well-known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2) that (which can be derived using real analysis, as shown by several answers):
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{c^2+n^2}=\frac{1+c\pi\coth (c\pi)}{2c^2}$$
From this, by using the substitution $c:=a/b$ one can easily derive the more general result that (note the difference in the lower limit of the sum):
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2+b^2 n^2}=\frac{-b+a\pi \coth(a\pi/b)}{2a^2 b} \tag{2}$$
Now, we can compute closed forms for the sums $S_1$ and $S_2$ by differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $a$ and $b$ respectively. We hence have that:
$$S_1=\frac{\pi^2 a^2 \operatorname{csch}^2(a\pi /b)+\pi a b \coth(a\pi /b)-2b^2}{4a^4 b^2}$$
$$S_2=\frac{-\pi^2 a^2 \operatorname{csch}^2(a\pi /b)+\pi a b \coth(a\pi /b)}{4a^2 b^4}$$
Therefore, by $(1)$, the integral is given by:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\cos(ax)}{e^{bx}-1}\ dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{\pi ^2    \operatorname{csch}^2(a\pi/b)}{b^2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 5):

Let
$$ I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{e^{bx}-1}\ dx. $$
It is easy to see
$$ I'(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\cos(ax)}{e^{bx}-1}\ dx. $$
Since
\begin{eqnarray}
I(a)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bx}\sin(ax)}{1-e^{-bx}}\ dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-b(n+1)x}\sin(ax)\ dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-b(n+1)x}\sin(ax)\ dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a}{a^2+b^2(n+1)^2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Using the result from @projectilemotion, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I(a)&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a}{a^2+b^2(n+1)^2}=\frac{-b+a\pi \coth(a\pi/b)}{2a b}=\frac12\left(-\frac{1}{a}+\frac\pi b\coth(\frac{a\pi}{b})\right)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I'(a)=\frac12\left(\frac1{a^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{b^2}\text{csch}^2(\frac{a\pi}{b})\right).$$

Comment: I must say that this method is quite easy (+1)

Answer (score 2):

$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x cos(ax)}{e^{bx} -1} dx =\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{xe^{-bx}cos(ax)}{1-e^{-bx}} dx , \forall b\gt 0}}$$
It's easy to see :
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\infty } xe^{-bnx} . cos(ax)dx=\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\infty } e^{-bnx} .sin(ax)dx}}$$
so we have ;
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{I=\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{a}{a^{2}+b^{2}.n^{2}}}}$$
But  :

$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^{2}+n^{2}}=\frac{-1}{2x^{2}}+\frac{\pi(e^{x\pi}+e^{-x\pi})}{2x(e^{x\pi}-e^{-x\pi})}}}$$
we can write : $$\displaystyle{\displaylines{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{a}{a^{2}+b^{2}.n^{2}}=\frac{a}{b^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(\frac{a}{b})^{2}+n^{2}}=\frac{1}{a}\left[ (\frac{a}{b})^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(\frac{a}{b})^{2}+n^{2}} \right]}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{a}\left[ \frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}} \left( \frac{-1}{2(\frac{a}{b})^{2}} +\frac{\pi(e^{\frac{a}{b}\pi}+e^{\frac{-a}{b}\pi})}{2(\frac{a}{b})(e^{\frac{a}{b}\pi}-e^{\frac{-a}{b}\pi})}\right)\right]$$

so we have :$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{a}{a^{2}+b^{2}.n^{2}}=\frac{-1}{2a}+\frac{\pi}{2b}.coth(\frac{a\pi}{b})}}$$
By partial derivative for both sides :

$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{xcos(ax)}{e^{bx} -1} dx =\frac{1}{2a^{2}}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{2b^{2}} csch^{2}(\frac{a\pi}{b})}}$$