# Is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2}$ irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2}\approx1.07169$$

I have viewed the proof of the irrationality of $e$ and $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but no idea with this one.

Comment: If $\pi\coth(\pi)$ is irrational, then that sum is also irrational, since we have that:
[$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2+n^2}=\frac{a\pi\coth(a\pi)-1}{2a^2}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2)

Comment: Thanks, That answers the question

Comment: Well, I don't think it really answers the question because proving that $\pi\coth(\pi)$ is irrational seems very non-trivial (although intuitively, it may seem like it). My first comment was just to show that we could reduce the problem to a (possibly) simpler one.

Comment: Usually , irrationality proofs are extremely hard (this does not necessarily mean that this is also the case here). Examples of numbers for which is unknown whether they are rational include $\gamma$ , $e+\pi$ and $e \cdot \pi$

Comment: It is known that $\pi$ and $\coth(\pi)$ are irrational. $\coth(\pi)$ is irrational, since we have that:
$$\coth(\pi)=1+\frac{2}{e^{2\pi}-1}$$
And $e^{2\pi}$ is transcendental (hence irrational), since $e^{2\pi}=(-1)^{-2i}$, so by the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), the result follows. However, from this one cannot conclude that their product (so in this case $\pi\coth(\pi)$) is irrational (do you know why?). If I had to guess, I would guess that this problem is unsolved.

Comment: So, the product of two transcendental numbers can be rational? @projectilemotion

Comment: Yes, consider for instance $a=e$ and $b=1/e$ (reciprocal of a transcendental number is transcendental), but $ab=1$. More generally, you could replace $e$ by any transcendental number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value is demonstrably irrational and transcendental. [Nesterenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Valentinovich_Nesterenko) showed $\pi$ and $e^{\sqrt{a}\pi}$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $a \in \mathbb{N}$ which implies
$$\pi\coth\left(\pi\sqrt{a}\right)=\pi\frac{e^{2\pi\sqrt{a}}+1}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{a}}-1}$$ is transcendental which implies

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+a}=\frac{\sqrt{a}\pi\coth(\sqrt{a}\pi)-1}{2a}$$
is transcendental for $a\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular, this means that the value in the title where $a=1$ is irrational.